# How to search and retain news data for the purpose of curation without any copyright issues

Tags: web-development, content, copyright, api, usage-data

I am currently using [The Bing News Search API](https://english.api.rakuten.net/microsoft-azure/api/bing-news-search/) with Rakuten RapidAPI in order to get news articles and curate them on my site. However, I just read the API's [display requirements](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/bing-web-search/use-display-requirements) which has restrictions on how to use the data.

> **Internet search experience requirements**
>
> All data returned in responses may only be used in internet search
>   experiences. An internet
>   search experience means the content displayed:
>
> 1.) Is relevant and responsive to the end user's direct query, or other
>   indication of their search interest and intent (for example, a
>   user-indicated search query).
>
> 2.) Helps users find and navigate to the response's data sources. For
>   example, providing clickable links from hyperlinks in the response.
>
> 3.) Includes multiple results for the user to select from.
>
> 4.) Are in a placement that enables users to search.
>
> 5.) Includes a visible indication that the content is an internet search
>   result. For example, a statement that the content is "from the web".
>
> 6.) Includes any other appropriate measures to ensure your Bing Search API
>   data does not violate any applicable laws or third-party rights.
>   Consult your legal advisors to determine what measures may be
>   appropriate.
>
> 7.) The only exception to these internet search experience requirements is
>   for URL discovery, as described later in this article.
>
> **Restrictions**
>
> Do not:
>
> 1.) Copy, store, or cache any data from responses (except retention to the
>   extent permitted by continuity of service.
>
> 2.) Use data received from the Search APIs as part of any machine learning
>   or similar algorithmic activity. Do not use this data to train,
>   evaluate, or improve new or existing services that you or third
>   parties might offer.
>
> 3.) Modify the content of results (other than to reformat them in a way
>   that does not violate any other requirement), unless required by law
>   or agreed to by Microsoft.
>
> 4.) Omit attribution information and URLs associated with result content.
>
> 5.) Reorder, including by omission, the results displayed in an answer
>   when an order or ranking is provided, unless required by law or agreed
>   to by Microsoft.

If I am interpreting it correctly, they are only allowing their api to be used for user searches, and they also have restrictions that prohibit you from copying, storing, or caching their data.

Can I create a curation site (similar to what [Digg](https://digg.com/) does) using this api?

Comment: Welcome to Webmasters! I agree the language is quite fuzzy. Cheers!!

Comment: I think the copyright issue isn't so much related to Bing's own ToS for their API, but the ToS of *all* the news sources whose content might be accessible through it. Bing's ToS is merely to protect themselves.